# How to get i18n locale in nuxt.config file (technologies: Nuxt 3, Vue 3, Vite)

Tags: vuejs3, internationalization, locale, nuxt3, nuxt.config.js

How to get the equivalent to **context.app.i18n.locale** inside nuxt.config.ts file in **Nuxt 3** ?

I am using  "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^8.0.0-rc.5" (the **@nuxtjs/i18n@next** one).

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Ii realized I couldn't, so I used a different strategy.

Answer (score 0):

With Nuxt 3 I have created a Pinia store in the project and called it localeStore. This is the locale.ts file code for the store:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useLocaleStore = defineStore("locale", {
  state: () => ({    
  }),
  getters: {
    currentLocale: () => {
      return useNuxtApp().$i18n.locale.value;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    translate(key: string) {
      return useNuxtApp().$i18n.t(key);
    }
  }
});
```

Then, inside other .ts files in composables or utils or whatever, you can import the store and use its currentLocale getter or translate function:

```
import { useLocaleStore } from "~~/store/locale";

const localeStore = useLocaleStore();

function t(key: string) {
  return localeStore.translate(key);
}
```

Comment: Hello, I was asking inside the nuxt.config.ts file explicitly, but thank you for the reply